# Copy instances of derived class based on properties with attributes

Tags: c#, inheritance, reflection, attributes

Suppose I have an abstract base class in which I want a `CreateCopy` method:

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    ///base stuff

    public BaseClass CreateCopy() //or public object, if necessary   
    {
        //?????
    }
}
```

Assume that all derived classes have a parameterless constructor and property fields (that can be) marked with some kind of attribute:

```
public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    [CopiableProperty]
    public string Property1 {get; private set;}

    [CopiableProperty]
    public int Property2 {get; private set;}

    //no need to copy
    public int Property3 {get; private set;}

    //parameterless constructor
    public DerivedClass() { }
}
```

Is it possible with this structure to write the body of `CreateCopy()` in a way that I can create new instances of the derived objects with the correct `CopiableProperty` fields?

---

Naturally I could make a `public abstract BaseClass CreateCopy()` and force each derived class to care for its own copy, but due to the size and amount of the derived classes, this would bring too much extra effort.

Comment: have you thought about using an intermediate class between the base and the derived class?

Comment: Yes it is possible, iterate through the properties, filter for your attribute and copy the values of the properties left.

Comment: Perhaps you could use a Json serializer. You can decorate the properties with JsonIgnore. Then your base CreateCopy could return a serialized payload of the derived class. You can then take that payload and de-serailize into a copy of the class? I think :)

Comment: Have you considered using serialization? You can use attributes to control which properties should be serialized or not. See https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationAttributes.htm#JsonIgnoreAttribute and also  https://stackoverflow.com/a/15788750/558486

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A fairly simple approach could be using generics and reflection:

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    // restrict to children of BaseClass
    public T CreateCopy<T>() where T: BaseClass, new()
    {
        var copy = new T();

        // get properties that you actually care about
        var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties()
            .Where(x => x.GetCustomAttribute<CopiablePropertyAttribute>() != null);

        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            // set the value to the copy from the instance that called this method
            property.SetValue(copy, property.GetValue(this));
        }

        return copy;
    }
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    [CopiableProperty]
    public string Property1 { get; set; }

    [CopiableProperty]
    public int Property2 { get; set; }

    public int Property3 { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{Property1} - {Property2} - {Property3}";
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var original = new DerivedClass
    {
        Property1 = "Hello",
        Property2 = 123,
        Property3 = 500
    };

    var copy = original.CreateCopy<DerivedClass>();

    Console.WriteLine(original);
    Console.WriteLine(copy);

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

This would print:

```
Hello - 123 - 500
Hello - 123 - 0
```

Another approach would be to take advantage of a serialization library, if you don't mind the dependency:

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public BaseClass CreateCopy()
    {
        string serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);

        var actualType = GetType();

        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(serialized, actualType) as BaseClass;
    }
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public string Property1 { get; set; }

    public int Property2 { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public int Property3 { get; set; }

    //parameterless constructor
    public DerivedClass() { }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{Property1} - {Property2} - {Property3}";
    }
}
```

Comment: Great thing with Generics. Thanks for the very complete answer. --- A "bug" that is easy worked around: if the target property belongs to the base class, it throws an exception when setting. (It would be complex if I had more than one level of inheritance, but here I just use the base class property without reflection).

Comment: @DanielMöller Huh, I knew I had to test this a little more. Glad you found it useful though!

Comment: Maybe using `BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly` should solve it, but then I'd have to go through each type in the hierarchy up to the base type.

Answer (score 2):

My solution uses serialization/deserialization, using JSON.NET nuget package.

No need for a method in the base class, you can use an extension method instead ([adapted from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15788750/558486)):

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public static class ObjectExtensions
{
    public static T Clone<T>(this T source)
    {
        var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(source);
        var clone = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(serialized);

        return clone;
    }
}
```

And then use attributes to control which properties should be copied or not - example:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public string Property1 { get; set; }

    public int Property2 { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public int Property3 { get; set; }
}
```

Using the code:

```
var obj1 = new DerivedClass
{
    Property1 = "Abc",
    Property2 = 999,
    Property3 = 123
};

DerivedClass clone = obj1.Clone();
```

Result - as you can see, Property3 has the default value in the cloned object:

[image: Clone results]

Answer (score 1):

Iterate through all properties in type and check your attribute with `GetCustomAttributes`. See code:

```
public BaseClass CreateCopy()
{
    var type = GetType();
    var result = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

    foreach (var propertyInfo in type.GetProperties())
    {
        var skipThisProperty = !propertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes(
                typeof(CopiablePropertyAttribute), false)
            .Any();

        if (skipThisProperty)
            continue;

        var value = propertyInfo.GetValue(this, null);
        propertyInfo.SetValue(result, value, null);
    }

    return (BaseClass) result;
}
```

Please pay attention to `null` parameter in `GetValue` and `SetValue`. If your property is indexer, you need to pass a correct value as last argument